# add css properties in using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have one image in my html and i have 5 different link, i want to change image background position using only one class, so i set parameters in function but it is not working ?

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function Bg(left,top) {

    $('.me').each(function (){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $('.container').css({backgroundPosition: left+ 'px', top + "px"})

            })

        })

    })




</script>
<style>

.container { width:100px; height:100px; float:left; background:url(../bike.jpg) left top no-repeat;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="me" onmouseover="Bg(50,60)">click me1</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="Bg(80,70)" class="me">click me2</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="Bg(120,60)" class="me">click me3</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="Bg(150,60)" class="me">click me4</a>

<div class="container"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't work. You have the values stored inline in the `href` attribute of each `<a>` and you never call the function itself.

You should move the background position in a `data` attribute like: `data-bg="x,y"` then use this adapted code:

```
   $(function() {
    $('.me').each(function (){
        $(this).on('hover', function(){
             var bgPos = $(this).attr('coords');            
             bgPos = bgPos.split(',');   
             $('.container').css(
                  'background-position', bgPos[0] + 'px ' + bgPos[1] + 'px');
            });
        });
  });
```

Comment: very close to my requirement but this $('.container').css({
                          backgroundPosition: bgPos[0]+ 'px', bgPos[1] + 'px'});
 line giving me syntext error

Comment: one more thing i am using coords="50,60" attr instead to data-bg because i did not find it

Comment: if i give only one parameter then it is working like $('.container').css({
                          backgroundPosition: bgPos[0]+ 'px'});

Comment: ya it is working thanks but i cant understand how extra space make it happen bgPos[0] + 'px ' , if i remove one space from right qoute it is not working.

Comment: That's easy. `background-position` takes 2 parameters, in our case pixels, in the form: `background-position: x y` (notice the space between `x` and `y`), where `x` is the horizontal offset, and y is the vertical offset. jQuery ofc follows this when it adds your custom values.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax for [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) (unexpected `,`) is wrong. Try

```
$('.container').css('background-position', left + 'px ' + top + 'px');
```

or

```
$('.container').css({backgroundPosition: left + 'px ' + top + 'px'});
```

instead.

**EDIT:** This is not how `.hover()` works. Either use `.hover` **or** `mouseover`, it's a bad idea to mix them. You can use the following code to solve your problem, however, I recommend you to have a look at the jQuery documentation. Try to to seperate your JavaScript logic, don't use attribute handlers whenever possible.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Bdz/)

```
$(function(){
    /* The following function will reset the background-position
     * if the mouse moves out of the given element
    */
    $('.me').mouseout(function(){
        $('.container').css('background-position', '0 0');
        // remove the following line in productive environment
        $('.container').text($('.container').css('background-position'));
    });

    /* The following function will set the background-position
     * to the given values. It has to be called in another function
     * (see mouseover in your code).
    */
    window.Bg = function(left,top) {
        $('.container').css('background-position', left+ 'px ' + top + "px");
        // remove the following line in productive environment
        $('.container').text($('.container').css('background-position'));
    }
});
```

Comment: @amit: T.J. added the missing `+`, try again. Please add all JavaScript errors you encounter to your question.

Comment: @amit: Sorry, I didn't look at your JavaScript at all, I noticed only the CSS error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax

```
$('.container').css({backgroundPosition: 'left, top'});
```

Comment: i want to add background position by its parameters like <a href="#" class="me" onmouseover="Bg(50,60)">click me1</a>

Comment: Same thing I am saying . Here the left and the top parameters are the one that you passed on onmouseover event.
You just need to copy and paste this line, inplace of yours in your code it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

## *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/abudef/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
function Bg(left, top) {
     $('.container').css({backgroundPosition: left +' '+ top});
}
```